# If $x^2 = a \mod n$ has no solution(s) then $\gcd(a,n) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Conjecture:**
>
> If $$x^2 \equiv a\mod n$$ has no solution(s) then $$\gcd(a,n) = 1$$

This isn't a question from a textbook or from some class, it is actually my own. I've tested it out for various numbers like $(3,5)$ and so forth. How would some math major/mathematician show this using unfamiliar logic and tools not known to common people like me?

Edit: How about the other way around?

If $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ then $x^2 \equiv a\mod n$ has no solution(s).

Comment: Let $n=4$. Then $x^2\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ has no solution, but $\gcd(2,4)\ne 1$.

Comment: Counterexample to the next idea: let $n$ be arbitrary, $a=1$.  $x^2=1$ has solutions although $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

Comment: As other comments have pointed out, neither of your statements is correct.  However I hope this won't put you off exploring mathematics!  This sort of thing is absolutely normal: you make a conjecture, find it is wrong, investigate further and see if you can amend your conjecture.  For example, maybe your ideas only apply to certain types of values for $a$ and/or $n$.  Eventually (hopefully!) you zoom in on something which is correct.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Consider $a=4k+2$, $n=4$, $k\in\mathbb Z$. $a$ is not a square (because it's an even number that $4$ doesn't divide).